# Disable pep8 check in syntastic for python files

Tags: vim, pep8, syntastic

I work with enough code that does not follow pep8 (that I cannot fix) and would like syntastic to not use the pep8 syntax checker. Any way to disable it?

Comment: don't you have to specify which syntax checkers to use? I have *let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['pylint']* in my vimrc. What is your *g:syntastic_python_checkers* set to?

Comment: that variable is not set for me at all

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If your are using flake8 as a python syntax checker you could do it like this (put it into your *vimrc* or *ftplugin/python.vim* file):

```
let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['flake8']
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args='--ignore=E501,E225'
```

You need to silence each error class explicitly (and cannot disable pep8 checking as a whole). See the [flake8 documentation](http://flake8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/error-codes.html) and [pycodestyle documentation](https://pycodestyle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes) (used to be pep8) for all error and warning codes.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, flake8 is powerful than pylint. Maybe `let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args='--ignore=E501,E225'` is enough for `flake8` only.

Comment: Here are all the pep8 errors, add them to effectively disable pep8: '--ignore=E101,E111,E112,E113,E114,E115,E116,E121,E122,E123,E124,E125,E126,E127,E128,E129,E131,E133,E201,E202,E203,E211,E221,E222,E223,E224,E225,E226,E227,E228,E231,E241,E242,E251,E261,E262,E265,E266,E271,E272,E273,E274,E301,E302,E303,E304,E401,E402,E501,E502,E701,E702,E703,E704,E711,E712,E713,E714,E721,E731,E901,E902,W191,W291,W292,W293,W391,W503,W601,W602,W603,W604'

Comment: Dead link for error codes. Flake8 specific ones are here: http://flake8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/error-codes.html pycodestyle (used to be pep8) are here: https://pycodestyle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes

Comment: @Lucas you can use error classes, such as E1 for all E1xx warnings.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Christians answer. You can also add specific checker args:

```
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args = "--ignore=E501 --max-complexity 10"
```